# PowerShell - Change attributes BULK to a list of users

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file, containing a list of users (samaccountname) on Column A.
On the additional columns  i have additional attribute values i would like to set
For each of these users:

' OFFICE ' on Column B, ' Department ' on Column C and Company on Column D:

[image]

Please help putting together in correct Powershell Synatx.

So far i have tried the following:

```
Import-Module Activedirectory
$Attribcsv=Import-csv "D:\powershell\ADuserinformation\SetUserAttributes.csv"
ForEach ($User in $Attribcsv)
{
Set-ADUser $User.samaccountname -department $._Department
}
```

With a different csv with Two Column: sAMAcountName,Department

But i got an error:

[image]

Comment: Please show what you've tried

Comment: edited, with code i have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this (First Get the user using their SAM Account name with `Get-ADUser` and then pipe to `Set-ADUser` to set attribute):

```
Import-Module Activedirectory
$Attribcsv=Import-csv "D:\powershell\ADuserinformation\SetUserAttributes.csv"
ForEach ($User in $Attribcsv)
{
Get-ADUser -Identity $User.Users | Set-ADUser -department $._Department
}
```

Comment: Hello Hasan,  am getting the exact same error as i mentioned when i tried  that.  "" Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value 
for the argument, and then try running the command again.""

Comment: If Users column is your SAM account name, then try the edit

Comment: Tried editing also, same error. this is very weird i get this error with other  csv/PowerShell im using aswell.

Comment: Ok i got around it, there was a problem in the CSV , i reopened it and fix it. now i am having another issue. for the department value , i had another value, so the value i am trying to replace this value using the syntax now, its not working, is there a syntax that can be used to replace the current values?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but personally I would not use the `-Identity` parameter here, because if there are typos in the input CSV the script will bomb out.

A more forgiving option is to use `-Filter` like this:

```
Import-Module Activedirectory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$AttribCsv = Import-csv "D:\powershell\ADuserinformation\SetUserAttributes.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $accountName = $_.Users  # make sure the header for this column is correct here!
    # now try and find a valid user object using Filter
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$accountName'" -Properties Office, Company, Department -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        $user | Set-ADUser -Department $_.Department -Company $_.Company -Office $_.Office
        # or use -Replace:
        # $user | Set-ADUser -Replace @{Department = $_.Department; Company = $_.Company; Office = $_.Office}
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User with SamAccountName '$accountName' not found.."
    }
}
```

Mind you that if any of the properties have a null or empty value the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet will return an error.
Check your input CSV for that.